# How to parallelly run code blocks in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, urllib, try-except

I am working on testing mass number of devices hence I am writing a testing program so i could automate the task.
Please bare with me because I am new to Python or any Programming language.
i want to be able to run the try and except code blocks parallely so that I dont have to wait 10 seconds for every new device that gets checked(picture over 1000 devices).
so basically:

```
try:
    preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", preflash)
    print("FAIL")
    sys.exit(0)
except urllib.error.URLError: 
    correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("IP address: 192.168.100.5 is reachable")
```

this code block should run parallely. if 10.10.10.2 is first reachable then it shuts down but if 192.168.100.5 is reachable before it then it should continue with the programm.

here is what the output looks like just for your reference.

[image: Fail picture]

[image: pass picture]

Any help is much appreciated and please go easy on me guys cheers!

```
print(100*"#")

try:
    preflash = urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.10.10.2", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", preflash)
    print("FAIL")
    sys.exit(0)
except urllib.error.URLError: 
    correct = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.100.5", timeout=10).getcode()
    print("Web page status code:", correct)
    print("IP address: 192.168.100.5 is reachable")

 
print(100*"#")
print("Fetching device variables")
time.sleep(3)
print(100*"-")    
# Declare url String    
url_str = 'http://192.168.100.2/globals.xml'

# open webpage and read values
xml_str = urllib.request.urlopen(url_str).read()

# Parses XML doc to String for Terminal output
xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_str)

# Finding the neccassary Set points/ Sollwerte from the xmldoc

time.sleep(0.5)
# prints the order_number from the xmldoc
order_number = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('order_number')
odr_nmr = order_number[0].firstChild.nodeValue
print("The Order number of the current device is:", odr_nmr)
print(100*"-")
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for threading

Comment: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/
Understand about the cores and how threading works in python. Try to figure it out.